# Get params using ExpressJS

Tags: node.js, express

I'd like to get a specific param using ExpressJS with "#" instead of "?" in the url...

My URL :

```
http://localhost:3000/#access_token=LMkdfkdmsklmfdkslklmdskfmsda
```

I'd like to get "access_token" and "req.params.access_token" doesn't work...

Anthony

Answer (score 4):

Short answer: you can't.

Longer answer: [fragment identifiers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fragment_identifier) (that's the part after the `#`) are supposed to be evaluated on the client and are not supposed to be sent to server. Your express app has no way of knowing them.

You could try to convert them to query parameters or path variables (i.e. by handling fragment identifier change in javascript) to make them visible server-side.